# Choosing from an array many

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, random

```
$first  = 1.22;
$second = 1.55;
$third  = 1.77;
$fourth = 1.3;
$fifth = 1.5;
$sixth = 1.2;
$seventh = 1.4;
$eighth = 1.8;
$ninghth = 1.9;
$tenth = 1.24;

$array  = array($first, $second, $third,$fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninghth, $tenth);
echo $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)]*$array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)];
```

This works but i need it to show me what variables were multiplied and also, assign a text value on them.

Comment: Why the java tag, please??

Comment: Assign your `$array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)]`s to variables, multiply those

Comment: Why not use [array_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)? And what do you mean by _"assign a text value on them"_?

Comment: i needed a multi dimensional array and i made it , it looks like this.    $games = array (
    array ( "First", 1.14 ),
 array ( "2nd", 1.18),
 array ( "3rd", 1.22 ),    NoW i need to randomly make multiplication of two of them. I want it to show the result of the calcul and the text asociated in the arrays

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should do it in two steps, something like that:

```
$array  = array($first, $second, $third,$fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninghth, $tenth);
$firstValue = $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)];
$secondValue = $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)];
echo "multiplying: " . $firstValue . " and " . $secondValue;
echo $firstValue*$secondvalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi dimensional array where the text is the first item and the value the second item and you want to show which text and value are multiplied, you might use for example:

```
$games = [["First", 1.14], ["2nd", 1.18], ["3rd", 1.22]];
$rand1 = array_rand($games);
$rand2 = array_rand($games);
$val1 = $games[$rand1][1];
$val2 = $games[$rand2][1];

echo sprintf(
    "The product of '%s' (%f) and '%s' (%f) is %f",
    $games[$rand1][0], $val1, $games[$rand2][0], $val2, $val1 * $val2
);
```

The output has the form of

```
The product of '2nd' (1.180000) and 'First' (1.140000) is 1.345200
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/rgOCK).